# Does my approach to defining the analysis period make sense?

Tags: self-study, sampling, sample-size

I’m a Google Data Analysis Certificate student, at my capstone project now. I’m switching from a non-data background and I’m aware there’re vast amounts of what I yet need to learn. Therefore in addition to direct answers I would appreciate some must-reads on the topic. Thank you all in advance.

**Context**

I’m asked to find differences between riding patterns of one-time and member users of a fictional bike sharing company (the Cyclistic case). The goal is to later recognize the potential incentives for casual riders to become annual members.

I have access to trip data from 2013 to October 2023, several dozen million rows total. The data comes from a real bike sharing company. The set of fields significant for my analysis stays the same throughout the years, but the data within may change: stations, bike types etc.

Now I’m trying to define the sample size to analyze. The project brief says I can just take any period between a quarter and a year and analyze it. I’d like to try to approach the task as a real-world one, thus a period of a year seems too small to define patterns (below I describe why). Now I want to understand the “real-world approach”.

**My approach**

AI proposes me to take several years and use stratified sampling: take some stratas (say, years or half-years, I’m yet to define) and extract random samples from them, basing on the expected margin of error and confidence level.

The approach seems fair, but I cannot decide on how many years I should reasonably take. I do not like the idea of taking all the 10 years for the following reasons:

- the more years I take the more manual processing and computing costs I have
- but most importantly, there’s been COVID within these 10 years that, according to several publications (e.g. some referred to [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2071-1050/14/21/13741)) , affected people’s bike sharing behavior. Namely, [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9672988/) states people started to make less member rides while non-member rides stayed the same, which is exactly what affects the patterns in question. Which means that if I take 7 pre-pandemic years and 3.5 pandemic and post-pandemic years, I’ll probably skew the results a bit too much towards the pre-pandemic normality. But if I take only 1 year as the brief asks, say 2022, which is a transitional one between pandemic and normality, it will be not representative either.

I’m considering the period from July 2016 to June 2023 and thus have 14 full half-years as stratas for sampling, equally distributed before pandemic and pandemic time. This would allow me to see both the patterns during the pandemic and the ‘normal’ patterns.

**The problem with my approach.**

On the one hand the above tactic seems reasonable.

On the other hand, I can’t help thinking I’m thinking too much. All the above thought process is beyond the required by the capstone project. The project brief asks for a year maximum, some of the bike sharing non-covid vs. covid comparison works on the Internet (e.g. referred in 4.1. by the [link](https://www.mdpi.com/2071-1050/14/21/13741)) still cover just a couple of years as well,  and despite the high number of my fellow certificate students I've failed to google anyone concerned about the analysis period.

So while I'm willing to do an extra-effort, I’m anxious it might be in a very wrong place.

**The questions**

Does my approach to define the analysis period generally make sense?
Or, if not, how would you approach it?

Thank you for your valuable input.